# How to get the correct primefaces theme look for selectOneMenu?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am working on a JSF Primefaces project with the omega theme. The look of the selectOneMenu dropdowns are not correct (missing line).

It looks like this:

[image]

It should look like:

[image]

Andy ideas?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="systemRoleMenu" value="#{configuration.systemRole}">        
    <f:selectItems value="#{configuration.systemRoles}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>omega</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    ..some more...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces Version 6 Extensions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces All Themes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    ...some more...
```

Additional information:
I already removed my own CSS to check if this is the problem. It's not.

Comment: what is the zoom factor in the browser? Is it set to '0'?

Comment: It's 0 (100%). Changing the zoom doesn't affect the missing line. It's the same in different browsers.

Comment: Does [the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) is work? It does for me in FF. It still looks like the fonts are bigger on your side. Maybe some 'minimal fontsize' setting in the browser?

Comment: In showscase it works, that's where I got the "how it should look" picture from. I tried in Chrome, IE, Eclipse Browser - everywhere it looks the same and is not looking like in the showcase.

Comment: Then check the differences in applied css with your browser developer tool

Comment: I read that they use some additional css in the primefaces showcase, so that's why the textsize and font may not be equal.

Comment: @Kukeltje see my answer. Your advice led to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Now due to more trying I found out that the root problem was, that I nested html documents by using`<ui:include>`. With this approach the stylesheets somehow confuse each other.

*Solution:* Adding `<ui:composition>` inside my included xhtml's. So everything outside the tag is ignored when included. Thus there were no more multiple html tags and stylsheet includes by primefaces. The problem was gone.

Comment: Please remove '1' since it is a workaround and '2' is the real cause and html documents should never be nested. The !important remark is not fully correct though. If you make the selectors more specific and the default PrimeFaces css does not contain any !important, than they are not needed. What you in the end effectively did was create an [mcve] and suddenly the problem disappeared. Next time, creating an mcve upfront helps a lot in getting to the cause of things.